# In Typescript, Is it correct that a literal function only returns nothing if it has `void` as its return type?

Tags: typescript

In the TypeScript documentation, Assignability of Functions, we see that
If the definition of a literal function has `void` as its return type, the function will return nothing.

Then

```
function f2(): void {
  return true;
}
```

The above function passes through and returns

```
const f3 = function (): void {
  return true;
};
```

Shouldn't only this function throw an error?
Why are they both throwing errors?

Is the documentation wrong?

TS Docs : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#assignability-of-functions

Comment: Why would you expect different results for these two examples? Why do you think one of them should not give an error?

Comment: @kaya3
Isn't `Function declaration` not a literal function?
Then shouldn't the f2 function throw an error as Docs says?

Comment: It does give an error. They both do. You seem to believe that one of them shouldn't ─ why?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#assignability-of-functions

I think that's what this DOCS says. `There is one other special case to be aware of, when a literal function definition has a void return type, that function must not return anything.`

Comment: Yes, so if you write a `return` statement which does return a value, then you get an error. The docs say you must not do it, and you do indeed get an error if you do it. What is the problem?

Comment: If by literal functions you mean all functions, I guess I'm wrong. But if a literal function is not a `Function declaration` but contains a `Function expression`, then the documentation is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: It's a bit uncharitable to say the documentation is *wrong*; it's just not *complete*, in that it says "function definition" instead of "function definition **or expression**". But then the example that follows shows both a function statement and a function expression, so it does seem to be conveying the correct information. The handbook isn't supposed to be a detailed language specification. Still, if the docs were changed to add "or expression" in that sentence, would you be satisfied? If so you might want to file a PR for it. Does that fully address your question or am I missing something?

Comment: The docs say "literal function definition", which is a bit ambiguous; the rule applies to literal functions and to function definitions. Not all function-valued expressions are literals ─ e.g. `f3` is an expression, which refers to a function by name, so the expression `f3` is not a literal function. But I must ask you again: **why** do you think only one of these should be an error, according to what is written in the docs? The docs say both give errors.

Comment: I thought the documentation was wrong because I thought only function expressions were literal functions.

Comment:  Yeah, maybe? If I look up terminology it does seem to imply that "function *literal*" is the function-body-expression-thing while "function *definition*" is a statement with a function body.  But it still really feels like we're trying to hold this handbook to an unfairly exacting standard.  If the handbook said "the Earth is spherical" and you said it's wrong because it should say "oblate spheroid" instead, then... I mean, yeah, I guess? But there are *sizes* of wrongness, and this feels small. If the handbook said "the Earth is a cube" then I'd call that "wrong".

Comment: Oh well I think this is probably an opinion question; either that or the answer is just "the documentation is essentially correct but if you think it could be worded better you might want to submit a PR in ms/typescript-website".... but that's opinion too, I guess?

Comment: @jcalz I think that "function definition" encompasses both function declarations (statements) and function expressions. It's more that "function literal" is a synonym for "function expression" where as in "a literal function" the word "literal" is an adjective in my understanding.